# Formatting: multiple print statements without spaces

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-2.6, python-2.x

I'm trying to print multiple things scattered in a loop. Here is an example:

```
print str(n)+" ",
for I in range(k):
    print str(l)+"+",
    if l>4:
        break
```

This gives me an out put like

```
10= 1+ 2+ 3+ 4
```

While I want it to give

```
10=1+2+3+4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason this happens is because a comma with the `print` statement forces a space between the two elements. You're best to construct the target output string inside the loop, then print it once. Try to avoid any sort of output being done in a loop if possible.

```
outstr = str(n)+" "  # do you mean `str(n)+"="?`
for I in range(k):
    outstr = outstr + str(l)+"+",
    if l>4:
        break
print outstr
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `sys.stdout.write` directly instead of `print`:

```
from sys import stdout

stdout.write(str(n)+" ")
for I in range(k):
    stdout.write(str(l)+"+")
    if l>4:
        break
```